# how to style a javascript button?

Tags: javascript, html, css, styles

Hello I am really struggling with styling the add button inside of this code

I am just learning javascript , so it is kinda confusing on which to call for the css class.

Check out the js fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/infinityswift19/6xwyc6tn/

Attemping to style this line >>

```
 <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="addItem(document.getElementById('ch1').rowIndex)" />
```

Thanks for any response.

Comment: What style info do you want to add?

Comment: Use `input[type="button"]` as a selector, and add whatever you want to that.

Comment: check out the jsfiddle the css is there , i just dont know what element to call the javascript button.

Comment: How is that "*a JavaScript button*" as opposed to "*an HTML button*"?

Comment: it isnt , i just found this code and cant style it .

Comment: its probably cause i dont know that much about buttons

Comment: styling the table or td is easy not so much the button

Comment: While you're permitted to choose the answer you want to accept (and not obliged to accept *any*), I'm not sure if I should point out that *you can only accept one answer.* I've just watched the checkmark bounce around a little, and it's bemusing but a little odd to see.

Comment: Yes this is my first question ever. All the information was helpful and technically an answer. It kind of makes me feel bad to only select one. I assume the checkmark gives the person some kind boost to their profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest adding a class to the button and styling it that way.

```
<input class="my-button" type="button" value="Add" onclick="addItem(document.getElementById('ch1').rowIndex)" />
```

Then in CSS:

```
.my-button {
    any styles you want go here
}
```

You should come up with a more meaningful class name than "my-button", but you get the idea. This is nice because you can reuse that class later if you need to. For example, if you have a link that also needs to look the same as this button, you can do something like:

```
<a href="http://wwww.google.com" class="my-button">Google Button</a>
```

Edit: JSFiddle with class added to first button: http://jsfiddle.net/ypLqjmwa/

Comment: awesome , yea i know that :) Can u try the js fiddle ?  I think it will give u more information as to what i am struggling with

Comment: @infinityswift Just edited my answer with a link to an updated fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, when you use the correct syntax:

```
input[type="button"] {
    border-color:#333;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/6xwyc6tn/2/).

Your CSS seems to be applied.

References:

- [CSS attribute-presence and value selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-selectors).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change **only** the add button and not every button in the layout you should first of all add a class to the add button:

```
<input type="button" class="add-button" value="Add" onclick="addItem(document.getElementById('ch1').rowIndex)" />
```

Once it has the class assigned you should select it in the css like this:

```
input[type="button"].add-button{ /*styles*/ }
```

You could only use the .add-button selector but remember that the input selector has preference over class selectors. If you want to be sure you can customize your button completely use the method above.

Comment: Is this possible    <input type="button" class="add-button", "add button2" , "addbutton3">

Comment: @infinityswift You can use as many classes as you want but the syntax would be like this: <input class="class1 class2 class3 class4">. Never use spaces in the class name because spaces separate different classes.

Answer (score 0):

You should use some CSS to style the button and the table itself. See my modifications to your JS fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/6xwyc6tn/1/
Added the following classes:

```
.td-no{
    border:0px;
}
table,tr{
    border:0px;
}
.btn-orange{
    background-color:#D25D12;
    color:white;
}
.btn-orange:hover{
    background-color:#D6A800;
    color:white;
}
.btn-purple{
    background-color:#4F3674;
    color:white;
}
.btn{
display: inline-block;
padding: 6px 12px;
margin-bottom: 0;
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 1.42857143;
text-align: center;
white-space: nowrap;
vertical-align: middle;
cursor: pointer;
border: 1px solid transparent;
border-radius: 4px;
}
```

Note that the styles were heavily inspired by Bootstrap because it is awesome :D
http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: Yea bootstrap is. Do you know any good any button active ideas? Other than a change in colour.

Comment: You can do a lot using JavaScript an jQuery. For instance you could have a "clock" that shows you the time when you hover over it. You could change the button image to make it look like it is a light that is off and when hovered on it switches to a "lit" picture. If you can think of it you can probably do it with some creative coding.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of styling the button, I would add a styled div element that has a javascript eventlistener on it like this:
HTML

```
<td><div id="button">Add</div></td>
```

CSS (I just did a bit of styling for examples)

```
div#button {
display:block;
background:lightblue;
padding:5px;
border-radius:5px;
}
```

javascript

```
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', addItem(document.getElementById('ch2').rowIndex));
```